# React.js textarea disabled and read only when name attribute is custom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why React is making my textarea disabled (refreshing default value) when I am inserting input inside the field? The problem is name field, when I put it just name='description' it works like a charm. But since I have diff. languages I want my field to look like this description[en], but the problem is React is disabling the editing of the field. I am beginner and learning React. Help?

```
<textarea
        className="form-control"
        id="description"
        onChange={this._onValueChange}
        value={this.state.currentData.description}
        placeholder="Short description (140 characters)"
        name={'description['+this.state.currentLanguage+']'}>
</textarea>
```

Comment: I think you read data from old state description, so you can't see changes

Comment: Textarea works plain if you post your _onValueChange code, it becomes clear